# How do I get the value from slider in the textbox in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a slider which is taking input from the user, I want to get that input in the textfield as the value of the slider keeps changing.
Following is the image of the slider and the textfield.
[image]

Code =>

```
SliderTheme(
          data: SliderThemeData(
            trackHeight: 8,
             ...
             ...
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 20),
                child: Text(
                  'Enter the amount you wish to add',
                 
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 28.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      buildSideLabel(sliderMinValue),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Slider(
                          value: sliderAmount,
                          min: sliderMinValue,
                          max: sliderMaxValue,
                          divisions: 50000,
                          label: sliderAmount.round().toString(),
                          onChanged: (sliderAmount) => setState(
                              () => this.sliderAmount = sliderAmount),
                        ),
                      ),
                      buildSideLabel(sliderMaxValue),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                child: Container(
                  child: TextField(
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        amount = value;
                      });
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(7),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

What should I do to get the slider value in the text field?

Comment: you want to show slider value in your text field right?

Comment: @AhmadRaza yes, that's what i want

Comment: I added the answer hope it will work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you. Refer [`Slider`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html)

declare int and TextEditingController variable

```
  int _currentSliderValue = 1;
  TextEditingController sliderController = TextEditingController();
```

Your Widget:

```
 Column(
  children: [
    Slider(
      value: _currentSliderValue.toDouble(),
      max: 100,
      label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
      onChanged: (double value) {
        setState(() {
          _currentSliderValue = value.toInt();
          sliderController.text = _currentSliderValue.toString();
          print(_currentSliderValue);
        });
      },
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        ),
        controller: sliderController,
       //if you want change the value of slider from textfield value
       /* onChanged: (text) {
          setState(() {
            _currentSliderValue = int.parse(text);
          });
        },*/
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Result screen->  [image]

Comment: It worked, thanks! Can the opposite be done also? As in, if I type a number in the textbox, the slider shows that value. Can we make textbox and slider syncronous?

Comment: I made it synchronous, added   sliderAmount = double.parse(value); inside the setState of the textfield.

Comment: Yes its correct. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

Here you can get slider value in your textfield, First create `TeztEditingController`

```
TextEditingController valueTextController = TextEditingController();
```

Then on change of slider perfome the following action

```
Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
               controller: valueTextController,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Slider(
                  value: 5,
                  min: 0,
                  max: 10,
                  divisions: 50000,
                  onChanged: (sliderAmount) {
                    print(sliderAmount);
                    setState(
                            () => valueTextController.text = sliderAmount.toString());
                  }
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

And you will get the updated value everytime on changing slider value

Comment: I got the values in the textfield,  but the slider itself stopped moving. Though I did get the answer. Thank you